# Changing the function to a reusable hook in React.js in functional component

Tags: reactjs

How can I transform the below function checkStatus to a reusable hook in React? I am returning the boolean value in the render component.

```
   const someComponentChecker = (props) => {
     const { isEnabled, isTrueMode, datasItems } = props
     function checkStatus = (data, isEnabled) => {
       if(isTrueMode && !isEnabled){
         return !data.isUpdate
       }else if(!isEnabled){
         return !data.isCreate
       }else{
         return true
       }
     }

      return (
        datasItems && datasItems.map((data, index) => {
             return <SampleComponent
                       enabled={checkStatus(data, isEnabled)}
                    />
       })

      )

   }
```

Comment: please specify why do you want to use hooks, what is your use case hooks are not the silver bullet

Answer (score 0):

A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

Unlike a React component, a custom Hook doesn’t need to have a specific signature. We can decide what it takes as arguments, and what, if anything, it should return. In other words, it’s just like a normal function. Its name should always start with use so that you can tell at a glance that the rules of Hooks apply to it.

If you feel that your function fulfills these criteria you can simply extract the code and create a new file with prefix 'use'.

But for your 'checkStatus' it doesn't seem like you are using any hook inside that. And its a very simple function. may be you can just make a util function and use it wherever you want.

Comment: okay, but how can i transform this into a custom hook. I was just trying it out.

Comment: create a new file say checkstatus.js and then rename your function to useCheckStatus and then export it from that file. And you are done.

Comment: You can read more about custom hooks here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html